# elasticsearch querying a part of a string

Tags: elasticsearch

An elasticsearch index contains data from database where _id is set to the primary key that is of the format

```
ACC000223344782
```

The key is of fixed length and has 0 padding after ACC as shown.
There is a need to search docs whose key ends at specific numbers

Some sample use cases are

1- Last digit is 9

```
xxxxxxx9
```

2- 2nd last digit is 3 AND last digit is between 0 and 5

```
xxxxxx3[0>=5]
```

3- 3rd last digit is between 3 AND 8 and last digit is 4.

```
xxxxxx[3>=8]x4
```

You got the idea. Basically random parts of the digit part of the  _id key.
To solve this problem, currently I have split the key manually into individual digits and stored as another field in the doc at the time of inserting data. That way the above key becomes

```
_id: ACC000223344782,
split_key:
  0:A
  1:C
  2:C
  3:0
  4:0
  5:0
  6:2
  7:2
  8:3
  9:3
  10:4
  11:4
  12:7
  13:8
  14:2
```

And then I can use the search query on the split_key field string index.

This seems more like a poor man's indexing. split_key field is totally redundant and I have a feeling that if I am using the elasticsearch the right way, it should not be needed. Can someone point me towards the right direction on any way to improve this and handle the above mentioned scenarios gracefully?

Comment: Your approach seems sensible. Making the key also a field to be used via [regexp search](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-regexp-query.html) looks like the way to go.

Comment: Interesting idea. And how do you query such an index structure? Can you give an example? Are you using `range` queries or regex?

Comment: You  can use regex groups. Such as 4[0-5] will match all numbers between 40 and 45

Comment: I wouldn't jump straight to using regexes, I like the idea of using separate fields for each digit and then using `range`s to match the documents. I would still not use regexes if there are other options available. Imagine a regex that has a wildcard (`*`) at the beginning. That's not an easy query to run in ES.